# Integration cannot be replaced by discrete sum

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a dense subset of $[0,1]$ .

Let $(c_n)_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n= 1$

> **Question:** Is it possible to have
> $$\int_0^1 f(x)dx= \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty f(x_i)c_i\ , \ \forall f\in C([0,1]) \quad ?$$

Clearly not, but how to prove it?

Comment: Can the integral be a Lebesgue integral? If so, choose $f=\mathbb 1_{\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q}$ and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @fKonrad: that choice of $f$ isn't continuous.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah, sorry i missed the $C([0,1])$.

Answer (score 10):

We assume WLOG that $c_1 \neq 0$. Take $f(x)$ to be a triangular bump centered at $x_1$ with some width $w$ to be chosen later and height $1$. Then $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \frac{w}{2}$. On the other hand, we can choose $w = w_n$ to be so small that the interval $[x_1 - w_n, x_1 + w_n]$ does not contain $x_2, x_3, \dots x_n$, which gives that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i f(x_i) = c_1 + \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} c_i f(x_i)$$

where $\left| \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} c_i f(x_i) \right| \le \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} |c_i|$. So as $n \to \infty$ the LHS $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \frac{w_n}{2}$ gets arbitrarily small while the RHS gets arbitrarily close to $c_1$, and so they cannot be equal.

This is just a straightforward formalization of the intuitive idea that the RHS overweights the values of $f$ at the $x_i$ for which $c_i$ is large.

**Edit:** Ah, there's a small gap, the argument that the RHS gets arbitrarily close to $c_1$ requires that $\sum c_i$ converges absolutely. I assume the intent was in fact to have $c_i \ge 0$ so I don't mind assuming this. And I guess if $\sum c_i$ doesn't converge absolutely then we can find a sequence of functions $f$ such that the LHS stays bounded but the RHS goes to $\infty$.

Comment: Interesting proof, which does not require knowledge in measure theory.

Comment: Right, this argument could be given by or presented to a student who has only seen the Riemann integral.

Comment: Nor does this assume $c_i>0$!

Comment: (There‘s one typo: $\ldots\le\sum_{i=\color{red}{n+1}}^{\color{red}\infty}|c_i|$)

Comment: @Hagen: thanks! I just realized the argument assumes absolute convergence though which is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 8):

I assume that the $c_i$'s are non-negative, so $\mu := \sum_{i \ge 1}c_i\delta_{x_i}$ is a probability measure on $[0,1]$. Call $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

If we had for every $f \in \mathcal{C}(0,1)$,
$$\int f\mathrm{d}\lambda = \int f\mathrm{d}\mu,$$ it would imply that $\lambda=\mu$. Indeed, by the monotone convergence theorem, the equality would be true for every indicator function of an open set (such a function can be written as a non-decreasing limit of continuous non-negative functions).

Since open sets are closed under finite intersections and generate the Borel $\sigma$-field, it would imply that $\lambda=\mu$, which is false.

Comment: Presumably you mean $\mu = \sum c_i \delta_{x_i}$?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected.

Comment: but why is it false that $\mu$ is not the Lebesgue measure, the question is all about that isn't it ?

Comment: @metaUser: for that it suffices to observe that the Lebesgue measure assigns measure zero to any point, while $\mu$ assigns nonzero measure to the points in $\{ x_i \}$. This corresponds to integrating the two measures against the indicator function of a point which is of course not directly available if you only integrate continuous functions. The argument in my answer basically amounts to continuously approximating such an indicator function.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the $c_i$ are positive.

Take a continuous version $f_n$ of $\chi_{[x_{i_0}-\frac{1}{n},x_{i_0}+\frac{1}{n}]}$ for a fixed $i_0\in \mathbb N$, then:
$$c_{i_0}=c_{i_0}f_n(x_{i_0})\le \sum_{i\in \mathbb N}  c_{i}f_n(x_{i})=\int_0^1 f_n(x)\text dx\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0.$$
So, by the generality of $i_0$, you get that $c_i=0 \;\forall i\in \mathbb N$
and this creates a contradiction.

Comment: I was trying something like that, but if you try to formalize it, it doesn't work, maybe I m missing something, but please try to construct such a continuous function and let me know if you can make it work.

Comment: You can do it with triangular bumps as in my answer, they amount to the same thing. The notation here is a bit confusing though. The $i_0$ is a little unnecessary.